Mapping Json during deserialization with different casing
I am facing an issue with mapping of JSON to my class.
When I hit the /greeting2 API from Postman, I get {} as response, but when I add @JsonProperty to the field along with @XmlElement, I get the correct output.
The problem is, that since Customer is a third party class, I do not want to change it.
I have the below controller class:
package com.example.demo.controller;
    
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
 
import com.example.demo.bean.Customer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
    
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getGreeting() 
    {
        String str="{\"global-customer-id\":\"1234\",\"subscriber-name\":\"test\"}";
    return str;
    }

    private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setPrettyPrint(false);
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        return mapper;
    }
         
    private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setPrettyPrint(false);
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .removeIf(m -> m.getClass().getName().equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class.getName()));
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(messageConverter);
        return restTemplate;
     }
         
    @GetMapping("/greeting2")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object getGreeting2() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate =getRestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Customer> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/greeting", HttpMethod.GET, null, Customer.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
    
}

Below is my Customer class:
package com.example.demo.bean;
    
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(name = "global-customer-id")
    private String globalCustomerId;

    @XmlElement(name = "subscriber-name")
    private String subscriberName;
    
    // Getters and setters
    
    public String getGlobalCustomerId() {
        return globalCustomerId;
    }
    
    public void setGlobalCustomerId(String globalCustomerId) {
        this.globalCustomerId = globalCustomerId;
    }
    
    public String getSubscriberName() {
        return subscriberName;
    }
    
    public void setSubscriberName(String subscriberName) {
        this.subscriberName = subscriberName;
    }
}

Below is my pom.xml, I tried to add all Jackson dependencies but it was of no use:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <springboot.version>2.4.0</springboot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I want to map the response from the /greeting API to my Customer class, but I don't want to use @JsonProperty annotation there, is there a way to do it without?

Just a note, for a minimal, reproducible example you only need the json, the class and an object mapper that fails the deserialization. Everything else just distracts from the issue.

The problem is the case - the json you deal with uses kebab-case for keys, while java field names, although matching, are in camelCase, as by convention. Since Customer is third-party, you have these options:

Configure object mapper globally to use kebab case naming strategy:

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.KEBAB_CASE);


Add the naming strategy for Customer only, using a mixin. Use @JsonNaming specifying kebab case on a custom class, and add it as a mixin for customer:

objectMapper.addMixIn(Customer.class, CustomClass.class);


Use custom deserializer. You can either register it with object mapper instance:

SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule();
myModule.addDeserializer(Customer.class, new MyCustomerDeserializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(myModule);

Or you can add @JsonDeserialize on a custom class and add it to customer as a mixin (see option 2).
